# Create custom inline element for RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, richtextblock

is it possible to create a custom inline object like "Run" and "Span" in RichTextBlock? 
 I didn't find any example or samples.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, you're can not create custom inline element because `ITextElement`, `ITextElementOverrides` or `IInline` are internal interfaces
Instead this, you can try to use [InlineUIContainer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx)

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Italic>This is an inline image.</Italic>

        <InlineUIContainer>
            <!--your xaml code here-->
        </InlineUIContainer>

        Mauris auctor tincidunt auctor.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Comment: My intention was to create an inline element that can handle background colors. Using InlineUIContainers allow me to create stackpanels with colored background and text but this objects are not selectable by mouse. Do you know a trick how to reach that goal?